# How to implement scroll smoothly for entire document?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please tell me how to make smooth scrolling of the entire site. Not on a button, just when you scroll through the entire site, so that it runs smoothly. For example, like on this site:

https://fireart.studio

Scrolling starts fluently and ends a little later, as you stop spinning the scroll wheel.
Prefer on pure JS/HTML/CSS.

P.S. `html { scroll-behavior: smooth;}` - not what I want.

Comment: I can't see any of that, I see it scrolling as any other website (Chrome on Ubuntu 18.04).

Comment: I can see it uses SmoothScroll.js: https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll

Comment: There are libraries that do this, but asking for them here would be off topic. If you are attempting to solve the problem yourself it would be worth talking about how you are trying to solve the problem, and including your attempt so far.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a css prop to your html element

```
html {
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Comment: The website OP linked doesn't seem to implement that style.